# ssh - Disable pseudo-terminal allocation

Tags: ssh, tty, pty

ssh client option "-T" is Disable pseudo-terminal allocation.

If I turn on this option, the remote sshd will not allocate a pty to run remote command. How the output of remote command transfer back to ssh client? As I know that the simple input/output between ssh client and server is:

```
ssh client <--- (TCP/IP) --> ssh server <---> ptm <---> pts <---> remote command
```

With option -T, does it means that the sshd will not create pty pairs to run remote command?

Answer (score 4):

If you turn pty allocation off with `-T`, sshd will use a pair of pipes instead of a bi-directional pty to communicate with the process running the remote command.

You can have a look at the [`do_exec_no_pty()`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/f5abb05f8c7358dacdcb866fe2813f6d8efd5830/session.c#L391) function in OpenSSH source code if that isn't documented anywhere. `dropbear` (another sshd implementation) is doing something similar.

In the case where a pty *is* allocated (`-t` option or no remote command specified), only a single pty will be allocated on the remote machine; the client ssh will not allocate a pty on the local machine; it will simply turn the raw mode on its stdin, if that's a tty.